# Qt/QString: No compiler error on misplaced parenthesis

Tags: qt, qstring

I just created a qstring from a double, but I misplaced the parenthesis. It did compile and the QString was fine in my computer, but the string had a lot of added garbage data data in front of the "1500 m" string I was producing in my friends computer.

My question is: What is actually going on in this codeline. Why doesn't it produce a compiler error?

```
double distance = 1500;
QString distanceString = QString("%1 m").arg(QString::number(distance), 'f', 1);
```

No compiler errors, and different behaviour on different computers.

Comment: You're calling `QString::arg(const QString &a, int fieldWidth, QChar fillChar)` with some weird values

Comment: Well, the thing is, because I misplaced the parenthesis the 'f' and the 1 is part of the Qstring.arg call instead of the QString::number call.

Comment: Yes, and it presumably does what that `arg` call would do. The counter-intuitive part here is that `'f'` implicitly converts to an `int` and the `1` implicitly converts to a `char` (which is some unprintable ASCII character).

Comment: So this is not a compiler error because the call to `arg` with 3 parameters is technically valid due to the values all being convertible to the parameter types.

Comment: @perivesta, you should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QString("%1 m").arg(QString::number(distance), 'f', 1)`
is calling the 3-argument overload
`QString::arg(const QString &a, int fieldWidth, QChar fillChar)`

So in this case, your parameters will go through implicit conversions:

- `'f'` converts to `int`, which is `102`
- `1` converts to `char` and which ends up being the `SOH` ASCII character

Becuase these conversions are allowed to happen implicitly, the call to `arg` is well-formed and so this is not a compile error.

The function then will do what is designed to do and replace `"%1"` with your number, but padded to a length of 102, padded with the unprintable `SOH` character. So you end up with a strange looking output.